# Phonegap Dreamweaver CS5.5 Android App

Tags: android, eclipse, dreamweaver

Hey guys it would really big huge if you guys could help me out. When I finished making my app in Dreamweaver it worked fine in the Emulator. Now when I go to build it and upload it to the market it asks for a certificate. I have no clue how to do that probably I keep getting confused. I dont know how to put it into Eclipse so I can sign it. Where does Dreamweaver keep the files to use in Eclipse where do I locate it? Or how can I make a certificate ? Please if you can give me a step by step. I tried following others but I cant do it. Big Thanks in

Answer (score 2):

you can find the way to generate a certificate [here](http://developer.android.com/guide/publishing/app-signing.html).
Dreamweaver generates an apk with the default android debug certificate. So your APK is already signed with the default debug key.
You need to unsign it by hand, for instance like this:

- rename your apk as zip
- unzip the file
- remove the META-INF folder.
- zip everything
- rename back as apk

then follow the steps in the above link to sign the apk with your personal certificate.

hope this helps